# Wireshark MAC address and NetBIOS name

Tags: networking, wireshark, sniffing

If I sniff a network with Wireshark every day to monitor three computers each day, these PCs when switched on will have different IP addresses.

At the weekend I would like to analyze the data collected, but I do not know how to filter the results because a single machine during the week may have had 5 different IP addresses.

I need to filter for MAC address or NetBIOS name, something that remains associated with the machine even after restarting.

Comment: Your question being...? Wireshark can of course filter by MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address is the best way to capture this information from the display filter.  If you are using some form of LAGG configuration on the devices, then you would simply have to string the two commands together for the two MAC addresses:

```
eth.addr == [MACAddress]

eth.addr == [MACAddress] and eth.addr == [MACAddress]
```

[image]

I hope that helps.